# have problems with my syntax code

Tags: sql, data-analysis

I have this assignment:
a. concatenation: generate a report listing vendor name and location as ‘name (location)’
b. the list above contains trailing spaces in both fields; trim the spaces and display results.
c. assign a name for the newly derived virtual column in the database
d. as a reminder, retrieve the number of products offered by vendor ‘DLL01’
e. retrieve the number of products offered by each vendor and display the results in two columns by
‘vend_id’ and ‘num_products’
I wrote some codes but it doesn't run.

```
a. select [vend_name] +'('+[vend_address] + [vend_city]+')' as 'Name (Location)'
from [dbo].[Vendors]

b. select 
Ltrim(Rtrim([vend_name] +'('+[vend_address] + [vend_city]+ ')' )as 'Name (Location)'
from [dbo].[Vendors]

c.select 
Ltrim(Rtrim([vend_name] +'('+[vend_address] + [vend_city]+')')),'   ','  '+ char(7)),
char(7),'') as 'vend information'
from [dbo].[Vendors]

d.select [vend_name] +'('+[vend_address] + [vend_city]+')' as 'Name (Location)'
from [dbo].[Vendors]

e. select [vend_id]='DLL01', count([vend_id]) as num products
from [dbo].[Vendors]
where [vend_id]='DLL01'
```

I think it is just syntax issues.

Can you help me?

Thanks!!!

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't run? What is the error? What DBMS are you using? I am guessing sql server based on the syntax so update the tags based on that.

Comment: For instance, question c I have this: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` for all columns in `c`?

Comment: I'm not sure about my code in order to create the virtual column: c. assign a name for the newly derived virtual column in the database

Comment: `c` you just need to assign a name. Not sure what you are trying to do with `char(7)`. `d` doesn't have the `WHERE` clause. `e` doesn't seem right; you should use `GROUP BY`. Look up how to use it and come back if you still have questions.

Comment: e. `select [vend_id]='DLL01'
from [dbo].[Vendors]
where [vend_id]='DLL01'
Group by count([vend_id]) as num products`      Something like that?

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I have tried to explain all the changes I have made. Let me know if you have any questions about any of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. Looks fine. Added a space before `(`

```
select [vend_name] +' ('+[vend_address] + [vend_city]+')' as 'Name (Location)'
from [dbo].[Vendors]
```

b. Added missing `)`

```
select Ltrim(Rtrim([vend_name] +' ('+[vend_address] + [vend_city]+ ')')) as 'Name (Location)'
from [dbo].[Vendors]
```

c. Avoid having column names with  (spaces) in them.

```
select Ltrim(Rtrim([vend_name] +' ('+[vend_address]+[vend_city]+')')) as 'vendor_information'
from [dbo].[Vendors]
```

d. Added `WHERE` clause.

```
select [vend_name] +' ('+[vend_address] + [vend_city]+')' as 'Name (Location)'
from [dbo].[Vendors]
WHERE [vend_id]='DLL01'
```

e. Added `GROUP BY` to get the count and changed the count to `*`.

```
select [vend_id], count(*) as num_products
from [dbo].[Vendors]
GROUP BY [vend_id]
```

I am not sure what the expectation is but you should be using `LTRIM(RTRIM(x))` on all columns since the spaces could be in any of them.

Comment: Thanks!!! just in e.`select [vend_id], count([vend_id]) as num products
from [dbo].[Vendors]
GROUP BY [vend_id]`???

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: question e. (*)

Comment: Depending on your data, the results might be the same. It is just more common to use COUNT(*) because you are counting the number of rows. You can use COUNT(1) as well. The difference will be if you need to count DISTINCT something.

Comment: With `count([vend_id])`, you will not count any records where vend_id is null. The GROUP BY will create a group for those but the count will not show correct results.

Comment: I have problems with this syntax: select 
Ltrim(Rtrim(concat(([vend_name] +'('+[vend_address] + [vend_city]+ +[vend_state]+ ')' )))as 'Name (Location)'
from [dbo].[Vendors]    can you help me? It is marked

Comment: b. retrieve the number of products offered by each vendor and display the results in two columns by
‘vend_id’ and ‘num_products’                                                                                  select count([prod_name]) as 'num products'
from [dbo].[Products]
GROUP BY [vend_id]

Comment: The first one...cannot have two `+ +`. `select vend_id, count([prod_name]) as 'num products' from [dbo].[Products] GROUP BY [vend_id]`

Answer (score 0):

For b you need to close your Ltrim parenthesis - you only closed the rtrim one:

```
   select Ltrim(Rtrim([vend_name] +'('+[vend_address] + [vend_city]+ ')' ))as 'Name (Location)'
    from [dbo].[Vendors]
```

Comment: select 
Ltrim(Rtrim(concat(([vend_name] +'('+[vend_address] + [vend_city] + [vend_state]+ ')' )))as 'Name (Location)'
from [dbo].[Vendors]
Can you help me???